# Cannot read the good value from element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, caching

I'm facing the following problem. (I volontary simplify the code in order to facilitate my explanation), The answer of my question is probably related to the way the DOM is updated.

I display a web page where I have the following DIV

```
<div id="dataComment16" data-url="/blog/index.php/post/comment?post_id=16" 
            data-param="0" ></div>
```

in my js script, I update the data-param in the following way

`$('#dataComment16').attr('data-param',250);`     -- update data-param

but If I want to display data-param just after  updating,

the command `alert ($('#dataComment16').attr('data-param'));`  still display 0

when I check the DOM with firefox  the DIV contains the following

```
<div id="dataComment16" data-url="/blog/index.php/contest/comment?post_id=16" 
                data-param="250" ></div>
```

but if I display the html source,  I still have  data-param=0

```
<div id="dataComment16" data-url="/blog/index.php/post/comment?post_id=16" 
                data-param="0" ></div>
```

My question is how can I do  to get the new data-param value?  (I'm using ajax)

Do I have to read the 'cache' instead of the page ?  and how can I do it ?

Any insights will be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you are calling `alert ($('#dataComment16').attr('data-param'));` before attribute is updated. If using ajax to update value, then call it inside success callback. Now regarding HTML source code, this is how the web works...

Comment: @A.Wolff  the alert line is just below  the update line

Comment: You mean your code is just: `$('#dataComment16').attr('data-param',250);alert ($('#dataComment16').attr('data-param'));`??? As you can see that works: http://jsfiddle.net/fJfYA/  BTW, why are you talking about ajax then?! You know, ajax is async by default, right?!

Comment: @A.Wolff    I put it just below the update to test whether I can get the good value.  Of course, the code is much complicated and actually I'm using callback to get value.  I used the solution proposed by unknown user (see below),  and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#dataComment16').data('param');
```

or

```
$('#dataComment16').attr('data-param');
```

Comment: When I refresh the page  (which I dont want because I'm using ajax to avoid refreshing),  the update and alert work perfectly.  And the DOM in firefox  has the good value  @Unknown

Comment: Yes it works !   thank you.  But I dont understand why